# Syntax error: missing operand after ' ' operator, Rowfilter&DataView

Tags: c#

I am using DataView and RowFilter, But i have this message Error:

"Syntax error: missing operand after 'complet' operator."

and this is the code, So whats wrong?

```
    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = new DataView(table);

    if (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()=="All")
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }
    else
        {
            dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Nom complet LIKE '%{0}%'", comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;

        } 
    }
```

Comment: If a field contains spaces then you should enclose it in square brackets _[Nom complet]_

Comment: Then i have an other message error: "Cannot find column [Nom complet]."

Comment: Then you should look at what are the column names of your datatable. DataView.RowFilter works on the fields present in the datatable not with the header names of the grid's columns.

Comment: how can i check column names of my datatable?